# C++: How to enter Unicode character and return it?

Tags: c++, unicode, io, character

As an exercise before starting Unicode-aware programming, I simply want to enter a Unicode character and return it. However, everything beyond 7-bit ASCII is swallowed (I tried `q`, `ä` and `ѿ`). Did I forget to include something? Is `wchar_t` not the correct type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t zeichen;
    wcin >> zeichen;
    wcout << zeichen << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest trying `char16_t` / `char32_t`. (`wchar_t` is defect and to be removed.)

Comment: Your  problem might not be in your application, but in your console settings. The windows console does not necessarily play very nice with unicode when using the standard streams. You could try using the [windows console api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-input-and-output-functions) or just reading and writing from a file. If that works, maybe you can fiddle with your console settings.

Comment: Probably you just need to setup stdin the same way you do with stdout: `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);`

Comment: Thanks @dewaffled, `stdin` did the trick. @lorro, for some reason, my program insists on `wchar_t`. Maybe it will go away when c++23 is there...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Unicode mode for `stdin` the same as it is configured for `stdout`:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
```